# Missing kernel for installing AMD graphics driver

Tags: kernel, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

Right now I'm trying to install AMD Catalyst 14.6 drivers onto ubuntu 14.04. I made the driver executable and ran it, but i got this error

> Please install the required pre-requisites before proceeding with AMD Catalyst installation. Please check file `usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` for more details.

I checked the log file and this is what it tells me.

> NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve package-dependency issues.
>
> fglrx installation requires that the system has kernel headers.  `/lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/build/include/linux/version.h` cannot be found on this system.
>
> Install kernel headers using the command `apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic`.

I tried to update the module but it says it is already in the newest version. I also went into my files and the `/include/` directory wasn't there.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I'm a bit new to Linux but I'm up for any solution. I just need to install these graphics drivers so my video rendering isn't so choppy.

Comment: What was the result of the suggested fix? `sudo  apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic`

Comment: `fglrx` won't instll on 16.04 either way.

Comment: More generally, you should install `linux-generic-lts-xenial` which depends on `linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial` which in turn depends on the most recent kernel header package for the 14.04.5 LTS kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6: It's 14.04 but the kernel is the same as in 16.04, so I guess the same applies.

Comment: Indeed. If you need fglrx, you'll need to switch back to the main 14.04 kernel and Xorg.

Comment: @dobey So, basically I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with the 16.04 kernels? How would I go about reverting to the 14.04 kernels?